# Peepso: Add extra data field (custom post meta) to postbox

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I know that this can be edited in the Peepso core, but I want to be able to update the plugin.

I think I found a filter I can use to edit the postbox and allow another field. The form is for the activity stream for logged in users. I found where to add the form but need to know how to add the date field properly to the form.

`peepso_permissions_post_create`

Answer (score 0):

I'am looking for the exact same thing, but haven't found the solution yet.

**Beware: the below code is from the legacy version from 2015...**

There is a event when an activity is saved ([see full code here](https://github.com/wp-plugins/peepso-core/blob/f788e50744c67197c707a89a0ac494d0ca15b162/assets/js/postbox.js#L216)):

```
    /**
     * Called on post save
     * @param {object} json JSON object
     */
    this.on_save = function(json) {
        if (typeof(Function) === typeof(this.opts.on_save))
            this.opts.on_save.apply(this, [json]);

        jQuery(this).trigger("postbox.post_saved", this);
    };
```

But I don't know how to get the data in the response. I can fetch the event like this:

```
$( document ).on( 'postbox.post_saved', ( e ) => {
    console.log( e );
});
```

But the JSON-Object from the `on_save`-function above is missing. Otherwise we could resend another ajax-call and save the extra fields on our own.